# How to use overlay mount to combine multiple directories with different sub directories?

Tags: ubuntu, mount, overlayfs

I have downloaded several git repositories arranged in different source trees:

1. repoDirs1 (with child dirs including vendor)
2. repoDirs2 (with child dirs including vendor)
3. specialRepos1
4. specialRepos2

To get a workable source tree, I have to do as following:

```
1. cp -rp repoDirs2/* repoDirs1/
2. cp -rp specialRepos1/vendor/* repoDirs1/vendor/
3. cp -rp specialRepos2/vendor/* repoDirs1/vendor/
```

This works but it changes the original repoDirs1 source tree and create difficulty for me to manage them with repo commands.

I searched and found that mount has an option to do overlays. However, after reading multiple examples I still cannot figure out how to write a correct mount command sequence to solve my problem. I either get overlayfs unknown or other bad option errors.

Could anyone please help to give a clear example? Thanks a lot. I am using ubuntu 20.04

Comment: The files are managed by vendor, repoDirs1 and repoDirs2 have different manifest.xml and specialRepos1/specialRepos2 are downloaded separately, and they have some overlayed child directories. I have copy specialRepos1 and specialRepos2 sequentially to get a correct result.

Comment: The repoDirs1 contains 500 repositories(aosp) and repoDirs2 contains several (<100) repos (vendor). I use repo init and repo sync to work with them. I don't know hot to use .gitignore to do that. And I don't want to copy specialRepos (create links is not a good idea either)

Comment: Oh sorry I misread, I can see what you're trying to achieve.  You're trying to coalesce two separate directories of modules.

Comment: repoDirs1 and repoDirs2 should have different repos (no duplicated repositories). But some of the deep directory are overlapped, so it is not convenient to create symbol links for repos from Dirs2 in Dirs1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Future readers be careful:**  This question is asking to coalesce two directories containing a lot of sub-directories.  This should not be used for normal git operations.  For that you should generally try to use the `.gitignore` file or [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).*

---

If you want to combine two directories into one place, even where there are overlapping files you can use a simple overlayfs mount.  In the context you are asking for this is best done as a read-only overlayfs.  If it was going to be read/write it would put all changed files in a separate directory.  It's highly unlikely that you're looking for that.

To create a readonly overlay you don't specify an `upper` or `workdir`:

```
mount -t overlay overlay -o lowerdir=specialRepos1/vendor/:specialRepos2/vendor/ repoDirs1/vendor/
```

---

Archlinux has a good description of this feature here:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Overlay_filesystem

Comment: Oh great, thanks. I tried it with a simple dir tree and it works. Before your answer, I did not know 1. workdir can be ignored, 2. target can be the lowerdir. One more question, in this case, will the file io performance be compromised a little bit? Can I safely go with it in the scenario of building 100G source codes without significant building speed change?

Comment: There may be very small performance hit, but I've never practically noticed one.  Bear in mind that to list a directory shared by both trees, both directories will need be to listed.  It's a pretty minimal overhead and the CPU to coalesce them is very small. But it does theoretically exist.